# How did I split the alphabet?

Tags: pattern

I have split the alphabet in two sets, as you may see in the picture below, according to a very specific rule. Which was the rule I used?

[image]

Comment: I guess random is not the correct answer?

Comment: I want to edit out the image and replace it with text, but that might ruin the puzzle. Is the font / shape of the letters significant?

Comment: @Doorknob冰: yes, the font is significant (this is why I used an image).  **The name** of the font (it's Arial, by the way) is not significant, however

Comment: This doesn't deserve downvotes... Gives +1

Comment: You still haven't fixed the `R`. In the font you chose (like most “stodgy” fonts that I could find), it can't be drawn without lifting the pen.

Comment: When I first read, it looked like "spit the alphabet"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The top set of letters are:

> Letters that have no curves but do have "branches" (ie cannot be drawn without lifting a pen off the paper or retracing parts of the letter)

The bottom set are those left over.

This does I think generate the correct sets (I'll be very embarrassed if I am wrong on that) but it feels a bit too complicated to be an elegant answer...

Comment: I am now suitably embarrassed. ;-)

Comment: Maybe I should add "or is the letter Z" to my rule for the top set. ;-)

Comment: Z has moved from the top set to the bottom set now. My prescience was obviously working well. I think this is correct now but still inelegant.

Comment: The way I draw a Z it belongs in the top set because I cross my Zs. =)

Answer (score 6):

AEFHKTXY

> The first set of letters cannot be drawn without lifting the pen from the paper and not drawing over what's already written (over the same path like a car on its reverse gear).

BCDGIJLMNOPQRSUVWZ

> The second set of letters can be drawn without taking the pen from paper and not moving the pen over what have already written (over the same path like a car on its reverse gear)

Comment: With the exception of `z` of course

Comment: Missed that. :( Will come up with a better answer soon.

Comment: Both `Z` and `Q` don't seem to fit by your criteria.

Comment: (ARGH! THAT'S MY FAULT! Q however is correct)

Comment: @mau - If Z is wrong, maybe Chris's now-deleted answer is actually correct?

Comment: Pesky Z! It foiled my attempt at answering too!!

Comment: @Doorknob冰: I think Q will fit the rule. In writing  Q it get intersected. But there is no need to go back over the path.

Comment: @randal'thor: Yes, he was right. Q actually may be written with a single stroke without passing again on some part of the letter

Comment: I was thinking the same, but then Z was there... Z and Q should be swapped for this answer to be correct.
EDIT: the original question changed... Upvoted again.

Comment: @mau According to you, the font does matter. And in your font, Q is written with the little line thing appearing on *both* sides of the circle thing (wow, it sounds like I'm talking like a second grader now :P). So there's no way to draw the Q without picking up the pencil or going over a previously traced line.

Comment: @Doorknob冰: start with your pencil on the bit of q inside the circle, draw to the circle, draw the circle, draw the last bit of the tail.

Comment: R however cannot be drawn due to the fact that the right "leg" doesn't meet the left leg but has a short horizontal stretch between the two (we are looking at them similar to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg )

Comment: @Chris Ah, clever; that is indeed possible. Didn't realize that.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 yes, in this font Q is written with the little line appearing on *both* sides of the circle. This means that for drawing it you may start at one end of the line, say the one withing the circle, draw a segment until you reach the circle, continue drawing the circle and when you complete it you draw the other part of the line.

Comment: The way to look at it is as a graph. Anywhere lines meet (or terminate) place a node. for it to be drawable in one stroke you need at most two nodes with an odd number of lines going in/out.

Comment: @Chris - I see the middle of the R as a line and a curve which are tangent.

Comment: @mau: I guess its subjective. I personally think it is obvious that the right leg and the loop do not meet on the left hand vertical. I did consider looking for the vector diagrams for the font but decided that was a little excessive since it is pretty subjective when just looking at an image as we are. :)