# Alphabet splitting extraordinaire!

Tags: english, language

Here are three ways of splitting the letters of the English alphabet into two groups:

1) **ABDOPQR**; *CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ*

2) **BCDGJOPQRSU**; *AEFHIKLMNTVWXYZ*

3) **DFHIJLNOPRTUVXYZ**; *ABCEGKMQSW*

In each case, the **first collection** of letters can be described simply using a one-word 'catchphrase' while the *second collection* is simply all those letters not in the first collection. First you need to find all the three catchphrases (this should be the only challenging part). In each case, determine how many distinct letters of the catchphrase are in the **first** and how many in the *second* collection of letters. You'll then have three pairs of numbers, and your final task is to find which of these three pairs is the odd one out.

What I really hope to achieve in this question is to get a collection of interesting alphabet-splitting puzzles, so that they're not all spread around the site in many [different](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/how-did-i-split-the-alphabet) [questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6422/what-rule-have-i-used-to-split-the-alphabet). The bit about catchphrases is just to unify this into a single puzzle so that I don't get people telling me I should split this into 3 distinct questions. After this has been solved (which shouldn't take long), I'll throw open the question to editing and we can incorporate all the interesting ways of splitting the alphabet that anyone can think of, and perhaps change or remove the catchphrase and odd-one-out parts of the question. **When editing a sequence into the question, please edit the answer into warspyking's now-accepted answer.**

---

**Your Puzzles;**

4) **ABCDEGJLMOQTUZ**; *FHIKNPRSVWXY*

5) **EITSANHURDMWG**; *VLFBKOPJXCZYQ*

6) **ABCIJOPQRSTUWY**; *DEFGHKLMNOVZ*

7) **COPSUVWXZ**; *ABDEFGHIJKLMNQRTY*

8) **AHIMOTUVWXY**; *BCDEFGJKLNPQRSZ*

9) **ΑΒΕΗΙΚΜΝΟΡΤΧΥΖ**; *CDFGJLQRSUVW*

10) **AEFHILMNORSX**; *BCDGJKPQTUVWYZ*

11) **HJKMNUVWXY**; *ABCDEFGILOPQRSTZ*

12) **BDEFHIKLMNPRTUVWXYZ**; *ACGJOQS*

13) **EFPTY**; *ABCDGHIJKLMNOQRSUVWXZ*

14) **BCFHIKNOPSUVWY**; *ADEGJLMQRTXZ*

---

If you think this is a silly way of posing a question, please tell me and give me a chance to improve it before hitting the downvote button. Let's be proactive here! :-)

**Edit**: I just discovered that more or less exactly the same idea appears in [Schott's Miscellany](http://www.benschott.com/miscellanies/schotts-original-miscellany/). His list is entitled 'Letter Traits' and is on page 76.

Comment: I like the idea of collecting a bunch of alphabet splitting puzzles in a single post. It might make the most sense to have a question along the lines of "What are some alphabet splitting puzzles?", and have each splitting be a different answer.

Comment: @JulianRosen - Good idea, but probably too late now. You could post this on meta as an idea for a new type of question. Meanwhile, now that squeamish ossifrage has solved this puzzle of mine, let's get to editing!

Comment: Is that what you mean by gathering them?

Comment: One problem with this idea is how would you downvote one bad puzzle when it's grouped with a bunch of other puzzles?

Comment: I understand why you want to make a collection post -- because of the mass-producible puzzles problem -- but lists don't make sense in this format. The idea of one item per answer is especially problematic. These are known as ["list questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124450/), and they [are a poor fit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98334/). (See [also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180335/).) There's no longer one correct answer, and in particular, voting on answers becomes almost meaningless; it's just "I like this", not "this is correct" (or at least "good").

Comment: @JoshCaswell Arguably challenge puzzles are a 'poor fit' too. It seems to me that what came out in the aftermath of TMBMP is that at this stage we can decide (to some extent, obviously) what's on-topic for Puzzling SE and what's not.

Comment: @warspyking Yes, this is what I meant. But now I'm beginning to think Julian Rosen's idea is better: create a question which just calls for examples of alphabet-splitting puzzles, and then answers will include both the puzzle and (spoilertagged) the solution. There'd be no accepted answer, and the *most popular* puzzles would rise to the top as Josh Caswell says. Could we have some words from a mod on whether this would be an 'allowed' question format?

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1729/what-about-a-question-calling-for-examples-of-a-certain-type-of-puzzle) now open.

Comment: @rand I've already included other answers to my answer so it can be complete and accepted :P

Comment: Lops I don't think a an arguable sequence is a good fit.

Comment: @warspyking Your examples 5) and 6) are also arguable. I've heard ETAOINSHRDLU for 5), and it's pretty unclear where to draw the line in 6).

Comment: @rand I got my source of 5 from Wikipedia. 5 seems pretty clear enough to me. If you're referring to k not being okay, it's because you don't here O

Comment: Maybe answers to edited sequences should get automatically get edited into my complete answer?

Comment: @warspyking I agree. See if you can solve Lopsy's number 7) then!

Comment: @rand Actually I meant when someone creates a sequence they create an answer in my answer.

Comment: @warspyking I know, but in Lopsy's absence you might be able to get the answer yourself...

Comment: @rand I'm trying, help me out here lol

Comment: @warspyking - Helped out! :-)

Comment: OOOHH I never would've thought of that.

Comment: @rand New one :D

Comment: Scratch's [sequel](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94644/logic-puzzle-alphabet-splitting-extraordinaire-sequel). Could you add it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Final Answer!*

Sequences;

1. **ABDOPQR**; CEFGHIJKLMNSTUVWXYZ
2. **BCDGJOPQRSU**; AEFHIKLMNTVWXYZ
3. **DFHIJLNOPRTUVXYZ**; ABCEGKMQSW

**ANSWERS** (credit to **squeamish ossifrage** for the 3rd answer):

> **1)** All these letters have enclosed space within the letters; Catchphrase *holes*.
>
>  **2)** All these letters have curves in them; Catchphrase *curves*.
>
>  **3)** All letters that correspond with composite numbers from 1 through 26; Catchphrase *composite*.

**NUMBERS:**

> {1, 4}, {4, 2}, {4, 4}

**FINAL ANSWER:**

> The odd one out is the *1st* pair **{1, 4}** because the other pairs are {even, even} while this one's first number is odd.

---

**OTHER SEQUENCES:**

4. **ABCDEGJLMOQTUZ**; *FHIKNPRSVWXY*
5. **EITSANHURDMWG**; *VLFBKOPJXCZYQ*
6. **ABCIJOPQRSTUWY**; *DEFGHKLMNOVZ*
7. **COPSUVWXZ**; *ABDEFGHIJKLMNQRTY*
8. **AHIMOTUVWXY**; *BCDEFGJKLNPQRSZ*
9. **ΑΒΕΗΙΚΜΝΟΡΤΧΥΖ**; *CDFGJLQRSUVW*
10. **AEFHILMNORSX**; *BCDGJKPQTUVWYZ*
11. **HJKMNUVWXY**; *ABCDEFGILOPQRSTZ*
12. **BDEFHIKLMNPRTUVWXYZ**; *ACGJOQS*
13. **EFPTY**; *ABCDGHIJKLMNOQRSUVWXZ*

**OTHER ANSWERS:**

> **4)** The **first group** are those letters in the odd columns of a qwerty keyboard.
>
>  **5)** The letters in (in order) the most frequent letters used, sorted just like the morse code sorts them. The latter obviously being least frequent (also in order)
>
>  **6)** The **first group** are those letters that when spoken in English sound like (or are) words. 
>  
>  **7)** The **first group** are those letters that look the same in lower-case as in capitals.
>
>  **8)** The **first group** are letters which can be reflected in a vertical axis and don't change.
>
>  **9)** The **first group** are [Greek letters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Letters) (did you notice it?) that look like Latin letters; the *second group* are Latin letters that don't look like any Greek letter.
>
>  **10)** The **first group** are letters which names start with a vowel.
>
>  **11)** The **first group** all have open tops, i.e. they would catch rainwater.
>
>  **12)** The **first group** all reach the upper left corner of their bounding box.
>
>  **13)** The **first group** all have an odd number of points where a stroke ends (one or three) where the second group have an even number (zero, two, or four.)

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out 3. Does it have to do with locations in the alphabet or just the letters?

Comment: Ha - that's for me to know and you to find out! :-) Any ideas on one-word catchphrases for 1) and 2)?

Comment: @rand al'thor Define *"catchphrase"* and give me a nonrelated example please.

Comment: See squeamish ossifrage's answer for 3 examples, but not unrelated ;-)

Comment: I've made a very small edit to the question, which should provide the clarification you need to finish the answer. I'm off to bed now; in the morning I'll have to decide whether to give the pretty green checkmark to you or squeamish :-s

Comment: There! On the record I got this before squeamish achieved anything.

Comment: I meant the odd one out to be {4,4} since they're both the same while $1\neq4\neq2$. The moral is that odd-one-out puzzles are bad since they usually don't have unique solutions.

Comment: @rand This looks like a better solution to me, perhaps just accept this?

Comment: Can we try to unify the formatting as well?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I added an answer for 10.

Comment: Also, I would say **6** is arguable

Comment: 6 also has O in both groups. Personally I think G should be in the first group and S in the second. The only reason I can think of to put S in the first group results in all letters being in the first group (and especially L, M and N).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [warspyking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/6436/40) has cracked the first two (I'd suggest **holes** and **curves** as catchphrases for these two groups).

I think the catchphrase for The last group is **composite**. The alphabet positions of the letters that come after the split ("ABCEGKMQSW") are 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 and 23 — i.e., 1 followed by all the prime numbers below 26. All the other numbers are composite, which means they are the product of two or more prime numbers.

Comment: Well done! You've basically cracked it; you just need the odd-one-out bit to get a pretty green checkmark, and then we can get to editing any alphabet-splitting puzzles anyone can think of into my question.