# Two Bowls of Alphabet Soup

Tags: english, letter-sequence, letters

These are three different puzzles with a similar format - feel free to solve them separately!

**1.**

H, J, K, M, N, U, V, W, X, and Y are.

A, B, C, D, E, F, G, I, L, O, P, Q, R, S, T, and Z aren’t.

**2.**

B, D, E, F, H, I, K, L, M, N, P, R, T, U, V, W, X, Y, and Z are.

A, C, G, J, O, Q, and S aren’t.

**3.**

E, F, P, T, and Y are.

A, B, C, D, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, Q, R, S, U, V, W, X, and Z aren’t.

Comment: [Relevant](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/alphabet-splitting-extraordinaire)?

Answer (score 11):

For #1 the letters that "are" all have open tops. What I mean is from the top you could put something in the open space.

Comment: Right! In my head, they "will catch rainwater."

Answer (score 8):

For #2 the letters are all drawn starting from the letter's top left corner.

Alternatively, the letters all have a part touching the top left corner of the letter's containing rectangle.

Answer (score 5):

**For #3:**

> the chosen letters are all formed with a single 3-way junction (in the typeface used here).  Some of the excluded letters have two 3-way junctions or a 4-way junction. In a different typeface, the set might be different.

Comment: Very good, although that's not exactly how I articulated it - see the answer here: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/alphabet-splitting-extraordinaire/6436#6436

Comment: @Luke, hm, I think Q has one end point?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>This a community wiki answer to bring together each individual parts of the answer. Please upvote the relevant answers as well if you are upvoting this.</sub>

---

**1.** H, J, K, M, N, U, V, W, X, and Y are. 
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, I, L, O, P, Q, R, S, T, and Z aren’t.

> The letters that "are" all have open tops. In other words can catch rainwater if used as a cup. (Maxqueue)

**2.**  B, D, E, F, H, I, K, L, M, N, P, R, T, U, V, W, X, Y, and Z are. A, C, G, J, O, Q, and S aren’t.

> The letters all have a part touching the top left corner of the letter's containing rectangle. (itriedacrab)

**3.** E, F, P, T, and Y are. A, B, C, D, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, Q, R, S, U, V, W, X, and Z aren’t.

> The chosen letters are all formed with a single 3-way junction. (Joffan)