# My Bowl of Alphabet Soup

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

Here's a simple one.

What happened to the alphabet?

`AEFHIKLMNTVWXYZUSRQPOJGDCB`

No hints necessary on this one.

Comment: Letters that contain only straight lines in the code font have been moved to the front in alphabetical order, and the other letters are at the back in reverse alphabetical order.

Comment: the other half of the alphabets with curvy bellies got drunk and swayed away from the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alphabet splitting extraordinaire!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/alphabet-splitting-extraordinaire)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I suppose it is similar to part 2 of that one, but it had a slightly different method. Either way. It's been solved and I must have missed that when posting. It's pretty far back.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. There is similarity, but the puzzles are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is:

> Ordered by curvature, and alphabetical

The first half are all letters with straight lines only, and are in alphabetic order.

While the second half are all letters with curves, and are in reverse alphabetic order.