# Logic Puzzle - Alphabet splitting extraordinaire! sequel

Tags: pattern, english

A group of Gobos is discussing how to divide the Scrabble tiles into two groups.
Here is what they suggested.

---

1. **ADFHJLMOQSUY**; *BCEGIKNPRTVWXZ*
2. **ABFKLMPVWY**; *CDEGHIJNOQRSTUXZ*
3. **AGIJKQXZ**; *BCDEFHLMNOPRSTUVWY_*

---

This is a sequel of [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/alphabet-splitting-extraordinaire) question.

> Solve it.

Hint for Clue 1:

> *Even* blind people can soIve it.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is:

> The first group is Braille letters with an odd number of dots in it.